# Magento: How to determine if customer aborted checkout process

Tags: zend-framework, magento, module, controller, checkout

I'm working on a custom module that needs to know if/when a user has aborted the checkout process. "Aborting" simply means they landed on the checkout's indexAction but didn't complete the process.  It's absolutely essential that I know if/when this happens.

I was thinking maybe set a session variable that they've entered checkout.  On each page load, have a block of code run that checks this variable.  If `true`, it will check which controller is being used.  If it isn't the checkout controller, I'll know they've left.

Two problems with my idea:

1. I don't have the slightest clue where to put this controller-checking code so it runs on each page load.
2. I don't know how to find which controller is handling the request.

I'd greatly appreciate if you could help answer those questions, or even suggest a better approach!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I need to know in real-time the instant a visitor left the checkout, I used a session variable named `IsUserInCheckout`.  This is set to `true` when the checkout's indexAction() executes.

I then created an event observer which ran before the request was dispatched to a controller.  It checks which controller is being called.  If the request isn't for the checkout controller, I look at the session variable to see if the user had started checkout.  Once I run some custom logic, I change the session variable `IsUserInCheckout` to `false`.

I feel like its light-weight enough.  It does run with every page load, but 98% of the time it justs reads the session variables, sees `false`, and does nothing.

Answer (score 2):

I'd take a slightly different approach to the abandoned cart problem.

Every time you "create a shopping cart" by adding a product, you're creating a Mage_Sales_Model_Quote that magento stores in the database.  Every time you complete an order, you're creating a Mage_Sales_Model_Order object.  Mage_Sales_Model_Order objects keep a reference to their Original quote IDs.

So, you can query for all the orders to get a list of quote IDs, and then create a quote collection and filter quotes for which there are orders.  This will give you a list of each time a cart's been abandoned.

```
//may start to degrade as orders pile up.  Add date filters to 
//prevent or look into properly joining things in.
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')
->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('*');

var_dump('Order Count', count($orders));

$quote_ids  = $orders->getColumnValues('quote_id');
$quote_ids = array_filter($quote_ids, 'is_numeric');

$carts      = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')
->getCollection();

var_dump('All Cart Count:');
var_dump(count($carts));

$carts      = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')
->getCollection()
->addFieldToFilter('entity_id',array('nin'=>$quote_ids));

var_dump('Filtered Cart Count:');
var_dump(count($carts));

foreach($carts as $cart)
{
    var_dump('abandoned cart', $cart);
}
```

As for your other questions, they're way too involved to get into a single stack overflow question.  I'd [read up](http://alanstorm.com/category/magento) on Magento to get a feel for the basic architecture, and then use the live [Commerce Bug](http://commercebugdemo.alanstorm.com/) demo to figure out which controller you're after. (both projects linked to above are mine, self link, buyer beware, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed help Alan! Unfortunately I needed to know in real-time (for the current user only) so your solution wasn't practical in this case.  I did learn alot from it though, and I really dig your Commerce Bug module! Thanks again :)

Comment: Thanks for this Alan, and as above I also really dig your Commerce Bug Extension!